# Is there a proof that zero multiplied by infinity = a real number

Tags: recreational-mathematics, infinity

Someone told me that $0\times \infty = 1$.

I am baffled by this because I thought you cannot multiply by infinity because it isn't a real number. If you can, is it possible to explain how and give some a proof?

Comment: Zero times infinity is undefined. There's nothing to prove here. Move on.

Comment: Your friend is demonstrably either wrong or using some very unconventional laws of mathematics.  In particular: if $\infty + \infty = \infty$, then
$$
1 = 0 \times \infty = 
0 \times (\infty + \infty) = 
0 \times \infty + 0 \times \infty = 2
$$
There are other examples of why defining $0 \times \infty$ is generally troublesome, but I think this will do.

Comment: @sas you get better results when you put the entire equality between the `$` delimiters.  So, in this case, it's better to write `$0 \times \infty = 1$` than `$0 \times \infty$ = $1$`.

Comment: An easier problem to demonstrate: we have
$$
1 = 0 \times \infty = (0 \times 0) \times \infty = 0 \times (0 \times \infty) = 0 \times 1 = 0
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, oh... I need a smile for "facepalm" emotion. You are right, I've just missed these two dollar delimeters. Can't change this now, my fault :(

Comment: @sas no big deal, just telling you in case you didn't know.

Comment: Wrong. $0\cdot\infty=e^{-\gamma}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ approaches $0$ and $g(x)$ approaches $\infty$ as $x$ approaches something, then $f(x)g(x)$ can approach a real number, and which number it is depends on which functions $f$ and $g$ are.  For example, suppose $f(x)=(5+x)^3-5^3$ and $g(x)=\frac1x$, and consider what happens as $x\to0$.  We have
$$
f(x)=(5+x)^3-5^3=(125 + 75x + 15x^2 + x^3)-5^3 = 75x+15x^2+x^3.
$$
Now simplify $f(x)g(x)$ and let $x\to 0$.

Comment: as x tends to 0, f(x)g(x) = 75. So in some sense, 0 x infinity could equal any real number, making it undefined?

Comment: @Orland : In this context, yes.  When working with integrals, one often defines $0\cdot\infty$ as $0$.  For example, in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left.\begin{cases} e^x & \text{if }x<0 \\ 0 & \text{if }x>0 \end{cases}\right\}\,dx$, what is the integral from $0$ to $\infty$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I'm not too sure, would it equal a constant?

Comment: @Orland : It is $\int_0^\infty 0\,dx=0$.  Thus in this context $0\cdot\infty=0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Is there a reason for the down-vote?